# Unittest error with Paramiko,Python,SSH, Router login

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, python-unittest

In my test setup, I have written a small unittest that just runs a login to a router. If this has happened postively, the test is passed.

Current problem that I can not connect via the IP address. See error message after output.

FUNCTION:

```
import unittest
import paramiko

class SimpleWidgetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):    #This class inherits unittest.TestCase

#----------------SETUP----------------
    #setup will run first
    def setUp(self):
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        #self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.connect(hostname='xxx.xx.xx.250', username='xxxx', password='xxxx')


#-----------------TEST--------------------

    #test cases goes here with 'test' prefix
    def test_split(self):
        #code here
        pass


    #this will run after the test cases
    def tearDown(self):
        #your code to clean or close the connection
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

ISSUE:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_split (__main__.SimpleWidgetTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37/Lib/py3-testcore/Switch_Test/Complete/TD_refactor/_test_account_disable_enable.py", line 11, in setUp
    self.ssh.connect(hostname='xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', username='xxxx', password='xxxx')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 402, in connect
    self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 768, in missing_host_key
    'Server {!r} not found in known_hosts'.format(hostname)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx' not found in known_hosts

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.002s

FAILED (errors=1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`

Add this line before connect. This may solve your problem.